# Cannot find the declaration of element 'kmodule'

Tags: drools

This error occurred while running PricingRuleDTExample (or any example) from [drools-examples](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/tree/master/drools-examples) on Drools6

```
2016-04-22 12:55:57,476 [main] ERROR Unable to build index of kmodule.xml url=file:/C:/Users/xxxx/workspace/drools-examples/target/classes/META-INF/kmodule.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/xxxx/workspace/drools-examples/target/classes/META-INF/kmodule.xml; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 52; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'kmodule'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because kmodule.xml namespace declaration is:

```
<kmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule">
```

which is pre-drools6 declaration. The fix was to change it to

```
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
```